# Square root of matrices with eigenvalues of opposite signs

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A \in \mathcal{M}_{n,n} (\mathbb{R})$, with one eigenvalue $<0$ and one eigenvalue $>0$ (and there can be possibly more eigenvalues too, some of which may be zero as well). Can we find say about existence of a matrix $B \in \mathcal{M}_{n,n} ( \mathbb{R})$ , for which $B^2=A$ holds ?

(Here, $\mathcal{M}_{n,n} (\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of all $n \times n$ matrices with all its entries $\in \mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: Yes they are real, but not symmetric. For symmetric matrices things like diagonalisation etc., could be seeked and then things like treating positive definite matrices can be imitated. But for the general situation, I failed to recognise anything that can crack this question.

Comment: If $A$ is diagaonlizable with real eigenvalues, then a real square root exists if and only if all negative eigenvalues have even multiplicity

Comment: @glS I don't have one to give and I don't care to write out the proof in a comment